# How to incrementally load data from Azure Blob storage to Azure SQL Database using Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a json file stored in Azure Blob Storage and I have loaded it into Azure SQL DB using Data Factory.
Now I would like to find a way in order to load only new records from the file to my database (as the file is being updated every week or so). Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: if my answer is useful please accept it as answer (click on check mark on left side of answer) to help other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the upsert ( slowly changing dimension type 1 ) that is already implemented in Azure Data Factory.
It will add new record and update old record that changed.

Here a quick tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzHWZ5_KMYo

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Dataflow activity.

In Dataflow Activity, you have the option of alter row as shown in below image.

[image]

In Alter row you can use `Upsert if` condition.

[image]

Here mention condition as `1 == 1`

Comment: This solution is working, thank you very much!